# Do you make a bracha achrona if the food you ate was bad?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, eating

Similar to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12934/making-a-bracha-on-disliked-foods) question, but I ask specifically about bracha achrona -- with the presumption that you probably made a bracha rishona before you ate. (Not that those mitzvot are necessarily linked, but it might feel weird to make one without the other.) Do you make a bracha achrona if the food you ate was bad?

Assume you ate the regular amount necessary for a bracha achrona.

Comment: How is this not a dupe? The question there didn't specify "rishona" and the answer dealt with both. What am I missing?

Comment: @SAH. If I understand your question correctly, in the link you provided it seems that the situation was that a person knew they were going to eat a meal that would not be to their liking. This might happen if one is invited to someone's home for a meal and for whatever reason, they really, really, really can't turn down the offer. In your case it seems that the person determined that he did not enjoy the food only after consuming it. Perhaps that distinction would provide an answer to your question........

Comment: ......That is to say a preconceived notion that you will not enjoy the food (he's a horrible cook) vs. someone who is bored with the "same old, same old" and decides to try something completely different and simply did not like it. Is that what you are asking? My guess is that a mandatory baracha is a mandatory baracha no matter what the taste situation is. After all, you still need to be thankful for the having food. If there was a situation that allowed you to forgoe a baracha I would go with the situation that you knew what you were getting into. Only a gut.

Comment: Can you define "bad"? If the food was spoiled to that extent it would surely remove itself from the classification of "food" and so not require an afterbrachah. If it's just not to your taste, then I suppose a brachah is in order.

Comment: @DoubleAA JJLL is correct. Also, in the other question, since you know ahead of time that the food will be distasteful, there is dispute about whether to make a bracha rishona. Here I assume the bracha was, in fact, made--implying, to some extent, a lack of knowledge about the taste.

Comment: @DoubleAA Any suggestions for edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the food was not your taste, a little burned, or similarly unenjoyable, you would still make a Bracha Acharona because of the nutritional benefit you derived.

If the food was so bad as to be inedible:
Eating inedible food is not considered eating, and gets neither a Bracha Rishona nor Acharona. (See Rambam) The fact that you already made a Bracha Rishona is irrelevant in deciding if the food gets a Bracha Acharona.

For example, if you drank a revius of medicine, you would clearly not make a Bracha Acharona.

Another different, but comparable idea (I heard personally from a world-reknown Brachos expert): If you drank a revius of water when you were totally not thirsty, you make no Brachah Acharona (even if you made a Bracha Rishona).

Comment: Thanks, this is really good. I'm going to accept the answer, but it would be great if you could edit in some sources.